# Relative Layout component at the bottom using <include > issue

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to design almost similar structure as defined in [Adding component at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297601/difficulty-with-scrollview-and-linearlayout)

I followed the answer given in that thread. But my problem is, if I use  tag to import another xml which has some components in `LinearLayout` and if I try to add that xml in my xml having `RelativeLayout`, the component which was imported using  tag won't go to the bottom of the screen. But strangely, if I replace that imported component with some component like a button in that same xml, the button goes to the bottom. Please help me.

Here's the code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Title Bar -->

    <include
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/title_bar"
        layout="@layout/title_bar" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip"/>


    <!-- Options Bar -->

    <include
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/options_bar"
        layout="@layout/options_bar"
        />

 <!--
    <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/> 
 -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please also share the options_bar layout. I think there is issue with option_bar height (may be "fill_parent").

Comment: @Arslan : Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. "match_parent" was used instead of "fill_parent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing look fine. Please 1st check you `option_bar.xml`. I am thinking the issue is its height. May be you have set the `option_bar.xml`

android:layout_height = "fill_parent"

If so then please change it to "wrap_content" or "match_parent".

Comment: Marked. But I think the problem is something else. Because, I have set both

`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

But still now it works fine.